# Сделать проще при создании списка

Tags: c#, linq

Сейчас реализовано так (ControlType - enum value):

```
private readonly ControlType[] _types;

private ComboBoxItem[] GetItems()
{
    ComboBoxItem[] items = new ComboBoxItem[_types.Length];
    int i = 0;

    foreach (ControlType type in _types)
    {
        ComboBoxItem item = new ComboBoxItem(type.ToString());
        items[i++] = item;
    }

    return items;
}
```

Как-то громоздко, можно же, наверно, и в одну строчку это сделать с помощью LINQ?
Плюс если можно, то как в этом случае будет с производительностью?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Видимо, так:

```
return _types.Select(t => new ComboBoxItem(t.ToString())).ToArray();
```

Однако использовать ToArray не рекомендуется, потому что выделений памяти больше, чем могло бы быть. Можно вызвать `ToList`. А можно вообще вернуть `IEnumerable<ComboBoxItem>`, особенно если это приватный метод, и вы контролируете его использование.

На фоне создания `ComboBoxItem` и прочего производительностью LINQ можно пренебречь. Не занимайтесь преждевременной оптимизацией.

Comment: про оптимизацию у меня был только сопутствующий вопрос. Основное - как быстрее просто написать код.

Comment: @YShinkarev Максимально кратко — это `_types.Select(t => new ComboBoxItem(t.ToString())` и вернуть `IEnumerable<ComboBoxItem>`.

Comment: Но мне просто интересно для справки. Возвращаются же часто такие коллекции. Почему именно массив? Пишется это применительно для Unity3D. А в сети часто наталкивался на утверждение, что используете  лучше массив, чем список (это касается в первую очередь объектов, порядок/состав которых после  не будет меняться. Не могу использовать IEnumerable (а может просто не знаю), потому что, в данном случае, на выходе я будут иметь некоторый SelectedIndex и мне же его надо будет вернуть потом...

Comment: @YShinkarev Опечатка, пропустил скобку, см. исправленный ответ. Для подавляющего большинства приложений разница в производительности пренебрежительно мала. То есть разница-то есть, но на "оптимизации" вы не выиграете чего-то, что можно заметить.

Comment: машинально смотрел, потом переписал вручную, всё стало нормально. И тогда последний вопрос - вернул я IEnumerable, а как мне вернуть быстро третий элемент?

Comment: @YShinkarev Если вам нужно обращаться к полученному списку по индексу, вызовите `ToList()`. Можно и `ToArray`, и разница не будет заметна, но выделений памяти может быть на одно больше.

Answer (score 0):

Можно короче даже без Linq:

```
private readonly ControlType[] _types;

private ComboBoxItem[] GetItems()
{
    var items = new ComboBoxItem[_types.Length];
    for(var i = 0; i < _types.Length; i++)
        items[i] = new ComboBoxItem(_types[i].ToString())

    return items;
}
```

Еще красивее без Linq, но с серьезным дополнительным оверхедом:

```
private readonly ControlType[] _types;

private ComboBoxItem[] GetItems()
{
    var items = new List<ComboBoxItem>();
    foreach(var type in _types)
        items.Add(new ComboBoxItem(type.ToString()));

    return items.ToArray();
}
```

Comment: по большому счёту это только разновидность, суть остаётся такой же. У меня только вопрос - почему вы сделали локальную переменную length?

Comment: @YShinkarev Привычка. Поменял. Если вижу свойство, стараюсь вызывать его только один раз, по понятным причинам. В данном случае скорее всего будет оптимизировано и так. Но, вообще, [рекомендуют проверять скорость работы](http://www.dotnetperls.com/array-length), если это критично (ищите там пункт Performance).